# Shrine::Error (storage :store isn't registered on ImageUploader)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shrine

The subject says it all.

I’m using shrine with a photos model.

When I upload file, the create action throws this error

Shrine::Error (storage :store isn't registered on ImageUploader)

I looked it up and everyone is saying to change the name of the shrine.rb to something like 01_shrine.rb so that it loads earlier.

This did not work for me. I have an image_uploader.rb in my models folder and a shrine.rb in config / initializers.

The weird thing is that after rails throws an error, when I navigate to photos route, the photo did in fact upload.

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be with your old records. As i suspect, by default config was something like:

```
Shrine.storages = {
  cache: Shrine::Storage::FileSystem.new("public", prefix: "uploads/cache"), # temporary
  store: Shrine::Storage::FileSystem.new("public", prefix: "uploads"),       # permanent
}
```

Then you uploaded file for test purposes and renamed initial "store" store

```
Shrine.storages = {
  new_cache: Shrine::Storage::FileSystem.new("public", prefix: "uploads/cache"), # temporary
  **new_store**: Shrine::Storage::FileSystem.new("public", prefix: "uploads"),       # permanent
}
```

Shrine tries to find the old "store" in your existing record and throws error

Comment: Ok so how do I fix?

Comment: You can try to update corresponding columns in your DB.

Comment: I’m sorry but can you explain like I’m five? I’m not getting this for some reason. You’re saying on my photos table I need to rename certain columns?

Comment: For example, if we have 

include ImageUploader::Attachment(:cover_photo) in the model

Corresponding model table has cover_photo_data column. For example, for record with 
id: 1, name: 'some test photo', cover_photo_data: {"id":"album/1/cover_photo/ac4ac698b8b6c96994b8e6b2e9d611f1.jpg","storage":"store","metadata":{"filename":...

So here you should change "storage": "store" to "storage": "storage_new".

Another viable option is to just delete old records if you are testing your application now.